# Proof that $\operatorname{span}(S_1\cap S_2) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(S_1) \cap \operatorname{span}(S_2)$

Tags: vector-spaces

An exercise in my book says :

> Prove that $\operatorname{span}(S_1\cap S_2) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(S_1) \cap \operatorname{span}(S_2)$.
>   Give an example in which $\operatorname{span}(S_1 \cap S_2)$ and $\operatorname{span}(S_1) \cap \operatorname{span}(S_2)$ are equal and one in which they are unequal.

Why are those two not necessarily equal?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1-st part: Can you show that $A\subseteq B$ $\Rightarrow$ $span(A)\subseteq span(B)$? If yes, the rest of the proof is just elementary set theory. 2-nd part: What do you get for $S_1=\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $S_2=\{2e_2,e_3\}$, where $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$?

Comment: @MartinSleziak 1st part: like so often, I think it's somewhat obvious that if A is a subset of B, then $span(A)$ won't contain any elements not in $span(B)$. Still I'm not sure how to 'prove' it in math-terms.

Comment: @MartinSleziak ok since $S_1 \cap S_2 \subseteq S_1, S_2$, $span(S_1\cap S_2) \subseteq span(S_1), span(S_2)$, thus $span(S_1\cap S_2) \subseteq span(S_1)\cap span(S_2)$. That itself makes sense to me so far.

Comment: no, the last step doesn't. How can I be sure that $span(S_1\cap S_2)$ does not always equal $span(S_1)\cap span(S_2)$, if I only know $span(S_1\cap S_2)$ is contained in $S_1$ and $S_2$?

Comment: Martin's example in the first comment answers the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will write $[A]$ instead of $\operatorname{span}(A)$ for the sake of brevity.

Of course, the proofs depend on your definition of [linear span](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span). E.g., we can define the [span](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aLinear_Span) of the set $A$ as the set of all linear combinations, i.e.
$$[A]=\{c_1\vec{a}_1+\dots+c_n\vec{a}_n; n\in\mathbb N; c_1,\dots,c_n\in F, a_1,\dots,a_n\in A\},$$
where $F$ is the fields we are working with.

**Observation 1.** $A\subseteq B$ implies $[A]\subseteq[B]$.

The proof is basically just observing that every linear combination of elements of $A$ is a linear combination of elements of $B$.

**Observation 2.** $[S_1\cap S_2] \subseteq [S_1]\cap[S_2]$.

From observation 1 we get $[S_1\cap S_2]\subseteq [S_1]$ and $[S_1\cap S_2]\subseteq [S_2]$, which yields $[S_1\cap S_2] \subseteq [S_1]\cap[S_2]$.

**Example 3.** We want to find an example where the inclusion is strict.
Let us try $S_1=\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $S_2=\{2e_1,e_3\}$, where $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$.
We can see that:

- $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$  and thus $[S_1\cap S_2]=\{0\}$
- $e_1\in[S_1]\cap [S_2] \subseteq [\{e_1\}]$ and $e_1\notin [S_1\cap S_2]$. So $[S_1\cap S_2]\subsetneqq [S_1]\cap[S_2]$ 
  (In fact, we have $[S_1]\cap [S_2] = [\{e_1\}]$.)

Comment: Thank you. Observation 1 and Example 3 seem obvious to me. I at first had problems to see why the first part of Observation 2 yields the second. Now I'm fine :)